# Return records that contain specific string but from the 7th character

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql field that has text such as "http://www.example.com/hello.php" in the "url" column.

I need some sort of mysql query that will allow me to find urls that have two or more slashes. Of course using '%//%' will return all of my urls due to the http:// aspect of the URLs.

So how can I get mysql to only look at urls from the 7th character?

Answer (score 1):

using underscore _ wildcard character to represent the first 7 characters (http://) followed by the pattern you are searching for e.g:

```
select * from urls where url like '_______%//%'; -- double //
```

or

```
select * from urls where url like '_______%/%'; -- single /
```

or

```
select * from urls where url like '_______%google%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html - you can do more with this

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE url LIKE 'http://%//%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions would be a good way to go.

select * from `urls` where `url` regexp '[/].+[/].+[/]';